# Content Type HTTP application/octet-stream is not supported in FireFox with JPlayer in MVC3

Tags: firefox, mime-types, content-type, jplayer

I'm having an issue with Firefox and the JPlayer (I think its the same problem in IE9): whenever I try to play a video in Firefox I get the following error in the console and the video wont play:

"Content-Type" HTTP of "application/octet-stream" is not supported.

[image]

well, translating, it means "Content-Type" HTTP of "app/octet-stream" is not supported. Load of media resources "name" failed.

It works fine in Chrome though. For what I have researched, it looks like that firefox has some problems with mime types and wont load anything that has octet-stream in it. However, I havent found a way to solve this. I read that I must declare the mime types in the IIS config. But I don't know how to make it work while debugging.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well, my problem was solved for firefox, apparently I had to supply only mv4 type 
instead of the basic mv4, ogv and webmv.

```
   new jPlayerPlaylist({
                        jPlayer: "#jquery_jplayer_2",
                        cssSelectorAncestor: "#jp_container_2"}, 
                        messageVideos , 
                       {
                        swfPath: '@Url.Content("~/Scripts/Jplayer.swf")',
                         supplied: "m4v"(used to pass "mv4", "ogv", "webmv")});
```